# Grouping element array php based first character value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array based MySql database.
This is the array.

```
[
  0 => [
    'id' => '1997'
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'YA4121'
  ]
  1 => [
    'id' => '1998'
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL2115'
  ]
  2 => [
    'id' => '1999'
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL4111'
  ]
]
```

How can I get the element `lokasi_terakhir` that grouped by the first character ? What the best way  ?

This is the goal :

```
[
   "Y" => 1,
   "P" => 2
]
```

Please advise

Comment: If it's in a SQL database, why not group it there?

Comment: Write some code to do: create a new array for your result, loop through the DB array, using foreach.  Then extract the value of array[INDEX]['lokasi_terakhir'], take it's first letter, increment the result array[FIRSTLETTER] + 1.

Comment: @FadlyDzil Your question may attract more downvotes and may be closed as Too Broad if you do not include a coding attempt in your question.  Please take a moment and add to your question what you tried before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two refined methods.  Which one you choose will come down to your personal preference (you won't find better methods).

In the first, I am iterating the array, declaring the first character of the `lokasi_terakhir` value as the key in the `$result` declaration.  If the key doesn't yet exist in the output array then it must be declared / set to `1`.  After it has been instantiated, it can then be incremented -- I am using "pre-incrementation".

The second method first maps a new array using the first character of the `lokasi_terakhir` value from each subarray, then counts each occurrence of each letter.

([Demonstrations Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6def71b2ea02a9ca5829b4b019a7e0589d705e5))

Method #1:  (foreach)

```
foreach($array as $item){
    if(!isset($result[$item['lokasi_terakhir'][0]])){
        $result[$item['lokasi_terakhir'][0]]=1;  // instantiate
    }else{
        ++$result[$item['lokasi_terakhir'][0]];  // increment
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Method #2:  (functional)

```
var_export(array_count_values(array_map(function($a){return $a['lokasi_terakhir'][0];},$array)));
// generate array of single-character elements, then count occurrences
```

Output: (from either)

```
array (
  'Y' => 1,
  'P' => 2,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group those items like this:

```
    $array = [
      0 => [
        'id' => '1997',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'YA4121'
      ],
      1 => [
        'id' => '1998',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL2115'
      ],
      2 => [
        'id' => '1999',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL4111'
      ]
    ];

$result = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
  $char = substr($item['lokasi_terakhir'], 0, 1);
  if(!isset($result[$char])) {
    $result[$char] = array();
  }

  $result[$char][] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array=[
    0 => [
        'id' => '1997',
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'YA4121'
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => '1998',
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL2115'
  ],
  2 => [
    'id' => '1999',
    'lokasi_terakhir' => 'PL4111'
  ]
];

foreach($array as $row){
    $newArray[]=$row['lokasi_terakhir'][0];

}

print_r(array_flip(array_unique($newArray)));
```

this code gets the first letter of the fields `lokasi_terakhir` , get the unique values to avoid duplicates and just flips the array to get the outcome you want.

The output is this :

```
Array ( [Y] => 0 [P] => 1 )
```